# How to make a Unity Android game resizable window option?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I want a little help in my Unity project I want an option to make the window of the game to be resizable I found out that Unity android builds do not support this option out of the box, Or i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Unity's default settings for Android builds do not provide a built-in option for resizable windows. However, there are workarounds you can implement to achieve this functionality. Here's one possible approach:

1. First, you need to modify the AndroidManifest.xml file of your Unity project. To do this, navigate to the "Plugins/Android" folder in your Unity project's directory.
2. If you don't already have an AndroidManifest.xml file in that folder, create a new file and name it "AndroidManifest.xml".
3. Open the AndroidManifest.xml file using a text editor and add the following code snippet inside the `<application>` tag:

```xml
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.2" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

4. Save the changes to the AndroidManifest.xml file.
5. Next, go to Unity's Player Settings by navigating to "Edit" -> "Project Settings" -> "Player" in the Unity editor.
6. In the Player Settings window, go to the "Android" tab.
7. Under the "Resolution and Presentation" section, set the "Orientation" to "Landscape Left" or "Landscape Right" based on your game's requirements.
8. Save the Player Settings changes.

With these steps, you have modified the AndroidManifest.xml file to force landscape orientation and added a meta-data tag to support aspect ratio resizing. This meta-data allows the game to scale up to a maximum aspect ratio of 2.2, which effectively enables resizing of the game window on certain devices.

Keep in mind that this workaround may not work on all Android devices due to hardware or software limitations. It's recommended to test your game on a variety of devices to ensure compatibility.

Note: If you plan to publish your game on the Google Play Store, you might want to consider checking the store's guidelines and policies to ensure compliance with their requirements for resizable windows.